# Trouble understanding rated values for a transformer

Tags: transformer

Say you have a 10 kVA 500/1000 V transformer and the transformer is operating at **full load**. My understanding is that then the load voltage would be |V1|=1000 V, and the load current would be |I2|= 10 kVA / 1000 V. But say we use the model of transformer below with an inductive load then V1>500V which its above its rated value of 500 V?

[image: Transformer circuit]

My question is therefore does full load mean that the primary voltage is at the rated value or the secondary? i.e that V1 is 500V but V2 is not 1000V?

Comment: kVA must be derated if PF load < 1 but rating is for output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *My question is therefore does full load mean that the primary voltage
> is at the rated value or the secondary? i.e that V1 is 500V but V2 is
> not 1000V?*

On full load, V1 is 500 volts and V2 is 1000 volts but, on no load, V2 will be somewhat higher than 1000 volts depending on how good your transformer regulation is. In other words, the turns ratio is chosen to counteract the droop in output voltage when taking full load current and, this inevitably means that no-load output voltage is greater than the rated voltage.